# MediaPlayer - long time between switching songs

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I have really STRANGE problem. When I was making MediaPlayer (it plays songs on /sdcard) it was working nice a very fast (normal working). When I made some estetic amendments (adding comments, changing onCliclListeners' functions for separated functions, etc), I saw my MediaPlayer need 6-7 SECONDS TO START PLAYING (first play, changing song, when song ends etc)

On LogCat it stucks at "prepare()", after few seconds it goes further. After each action (first play, change song..) it invoke play() method, which consists of:

```
try{
mp.reset()
mp.setDataSource(...);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
}
```

I have NO IDEA what is wrong :( before I spend week for looking for reason, maybe someone know why it takes so long and give me prompt?

Comment: Without more code it's difficult to point to the problem...

Answer (score 0):

That's why it's recommended to use `prepareAsync()` instead of `prepare()` method. `prepareAsync()` executes preparing in separate thread so your interface won't hang up.

Comment: But the question is why "preparation" takes so long?? If I use prepareAsync, probably it takes the same time but it won't block my app (?)

Comment: maybe you don't properly release your media player, that's why after several starts it begins to stuck